# How does a client know when to wake up and listen to a beacon?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, mac

In wireless networking, for power efficiency the access point(AP) sends a beacon to inform the client of pending packets periodically and the client only wakes up every beacon interval (e.g. 100msec) to listen to beacons.

However, a client have no idea about the specific time when a beacon arrives. How does it know when to wake up and get the beacon?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Beacon frames contain timestamps which the client uses to update its clock. Technically it does know when a beacon arrives due to this.

A client is expected to wake up and listen to a minimum of one beacon when the listening time is up.

HTH.

Comment: @HyZhang [this](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/1492071/80211-Beacons-Revealed.htm) has a lot of detail backing up APA's answer too.